# What does setmode, setup, output and cleanup do in the RPi.GPIO library?

Tags: python

I have been working on a project and everything is working.  I just want a bit more insight on what every line of code does.  It's one thing to write it,  it's completely different to understand it.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # I know the import code
import time

# I AM MORE KEEN TO FIND OUT THE NEXT FEW LINES MEANINGS AND WHAT THEY DO,

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(5) # I KNOW THIS 
GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()

print "Done!" # I KNOW THIS
```

Comment: `It's one thing to write it, it's completely different to understand it.` - begs the question "How did you know what to write, if you didn't know what you were doing?"

Comment: this is code that was given as a example that i tested and i understand most of it, just the pi stuff that i did not really understand as that was not explained in detail.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `setmode()` determines the GPIO numbering scheme to be used in the script (there are at least three different numbering schemes in common usage).

GPIO (General Purpose Input Output) may be selected as inputs or outputs (as well as other more specialised functions).  The `setup()` says GPIO 4 is to be used as an output.

The `output()` sets the level of the GPIO to on or off (also known as high/low, 1/0, True/False etc.).

The `cleanup()` switches all GPIO you used back to being inputs.  This is thought by some to be safer than leaving them as outputs.

See https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

Comment: Thanks Joan, it makes sense now that you explained. i had code with high and low, input and output and it did not make sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To see the documentation to these functions you can run

```
pydoc RPi.GPIO
```

or `import RPi.GPIO` and then `help(RPi.GPIO)`.

To actually see what the functions do in the code, from [C source code of RPi.GPIO](http://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c):

- `module_setup(...)` is described on [L113](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L113)
- `setup(...)` is described on [L209](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L209)
- `setmode(...)` is described on [L361](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L489)
- `cleanup(...)` is described on [L139](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L139)
- `output(...)` is described on [L258](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L258), [L283](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L283) and [L302](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L302)

All commands are described on [L428](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blob/master/source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c#L428):

```
{"setup", (PyCFunction)py_setup_channel, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Set up the GPIO channel, direction and (optional) pull/up down control\nchannel    - Either: RPi board pin number (not BCM GPIO 00..nn number).  Pins start from 1\n                or     : BCM GPIO number\ndirection - INPUT or OUTPUT\n[pull_up_down] - PUD_OFF (default), PUD_UP or PUD_DOWN\n[initial]        - Initial value for an output channel"},
{"cleanup", py_cleanup, METH_VARARGS, "Clean up by resetting all GPIO channels that have been used by this program\nto INPUT with no pullup/pulldown and no event detection"},
{"output", py_output_gpio, METH_VARARGS, "Output to a GPIO channel"},
{"input", py_input_gpio, METH_VARARGS, "Input from a GPIO channel"},
{"setmode", setmode, METH_VARARGS, "Set up numbering mode to use for channels.\nBOARD - Use Raspberry Pi board numbers\nBCM    - Use Broadcom GPIO 00..nn numbers"},
{"setwarnings", py_setwarnings, METH_VARARGS, "Enable or disable warning messages"},
```